# Having trouble displaying a secondary array within an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So i have an array of slide image urls which i'm looping through here called slides.

```
<div class="presentForm" id="presentForm{{$index}}"  ng:repeat="slide in slides" style="display: none;">
  <img id ="presentationSlide" ng-src='{{slide}}' style="height: 300px" width="600px">
  <label id="scriptLabel{{$index}}" for="slideScript{{$index}}" style="left:130px;">
    Slide {{$index + 1}} Script
  </label>
  <textarea class="scriptText" name="Text" id="slideScript{{$index}}" ng-model="scripts{{index}}">

  </textarea>
</div>
```

My problem arrises from the fact that I want to display a seconday array within this ng-repeat called scripts. The problem arises from the fact that scripts length might not match slides length (every slide might not have a script). So how could I display scripts[0] within the `<textarea></textarea>` but if scripts[3] doesn't exist display a blank text area?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very thorough answer, but nested `ng-repeat`'s should solve your problem. Let me know if I'm missing something.

**EDIT**: After re-reading your code. I think you might also need to rethink your data structure. scripts should be inside the slide object.

e.g.

```
slide = {name: 'slide1', scripts: ['script1', 'script2']}
```

Comment: ok so how incorpate object attributes in the html. For instance if I recreate slides to be an object like slides = []... slides[0] = {name:'someURl', script: 'some text'}

Comment: {{slide.name}} and {{slide.script}}